# Combine a list of tuples and list, removing the tuple elements from the list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples and a list:
    tup = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7)]
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

The tuples are actually, bigrams of the list a and are of the same order.

I have to combine these two structures, such that: 
I obtain a list:

```
[(1,2),3,4,5,6,7]
[1,(2,3),4,5,6,7]
[1,2,(3,4),5,6,7]
[1,2,3,(4,5),6,7]
```

The numbers have no contraints, so the lists could have duplicates or be distinct. 
This ain't a homework problem, I'm trying to implement a algorithm which requires this and for some reason, I'm unable to come up with a good method of doing this.

Sorry my question was unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Will the tuples in the list of tuples always appear somewhere in the list (and if they do, will they always appear together)? Will they always be a 2-tuple? Will they always be in order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question isn't very clear.
At first I thought you meant this

```
>>> tup = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7)]
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> for i,j in enumerate(tup):
...  print a[:i]+[j]+a[i+2:]
... 
[(1, 2), 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, (2, 3), 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, (3, 4), 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, (4, 5), 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, (5, 6), 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, (6, 7)]
```

But the I thought of another interpretation

```
>>> for i,j in enumerate(tup):
...  print a[:i]+[tuple(a[j[0]-1:j[1]])]+a[i+2:]
... 
[(1, 2), 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, (2, 3), 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, (3, 4), 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, (4, 5), 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, (5, 6), 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, (6, 7)]
```

It's really unfortunate that you chose the same numbers for `tup` and `a` if they are different in the general case

Answer (score 0):

This should be a little more generic and tolerant than most of the other options, if I'm understanding what you're asking for:

```
import bisect
[a[:bisect.bisect_left(a, lo)] + \
        [(lo, hi)] + \
        a[bisect.bisect_right(a, hi):] for (lo, hi) in tup]
```

Output is

```
[[(1, 2), 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [1, (2, 3), 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [1, 2, (3, 4), 5, 6, 7],
 [1, 2, 3, (4, 5), 6, 7],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, (5, 6), 7],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, (6, 7)]]
```

Comment: Ah, reading the question again, it looks like maybe the numbers are arbitrary, and you just want to sort of "zip" whatever values together, like gnibbler did.